# Cannot get WPF application to return to topmost app in window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, notifyicon

I'm using [NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) to implement a "minimize icon to tray" feature in my WPF app. The minimize works just fine, however if I click "open", the icon will re-appear on the taskbar but the app doesn't re-appear. I'm setting the `TopMost` property to `true` (I've tried the two solutions below) but still no luck. Very new to desktop apps so any direction/theories much appreciated.

**Code Behind**

```
    private void TrayIconShowWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // Neither of these work
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost = true;
        Topmost = true;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<taskbar:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Open Window" Click="TrayIconShowWindow_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Assets/OpenScreen.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="TrayIconExitApp_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Assets/Close.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</taskbar:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: have you tried the first 2 againstApplication.Current.MainWindow ? as currently you are appling to the TaskbarIcon

Comment: How so? The `TrayIconShowWindow_Click` is in my main window class.

Comment: Have you tried `myWindow.Activate();` `Topmost` is a setting so that the window is always the topmost but it doesn't display the window if minimized

Comment: @NealR If you select the item in the taskbar does it display?

Comment: @CathalMF yes if I click the taskbar icon, when it reappears, the window will come up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Activate method on the Window

```
private void TrayIconShowWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Activate();
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result

Comment: How are you hiding the window? Just using the standard minimize button on the Window?

Comment: Using a `Window_StateChanged` event and setting the `Visibility=Visibility.HIdden`

Comment: @NealR Ah that will be your problem, every time you set the window back to visible, that event handler will hide it again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```